# React Hook "useState" is called in function "AAA" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, function, react-hooks

i got this error for this code fragment.

```
const AB= () => {

  const [A, setA] = useState<AT| null>(null);
  const [B, setB] = useState<string>('0px');

..more}
```

Comment: convert `klageHome` to a function component.

Comment: it doen't work. display same error after convert function

Comment: Please provide [mcve] and format your code properly. thanks.

Comment: sure i edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pascal case for component name, and import react and useState if not already done so.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const KlageHome = () => {
  const [matrikkelnummer, setMatrikkelnummer] = useState(null); 
  const [panelHeight, setPanelHeight] = useState('0px')
  return (
    <div>{panelHeight}</div>
  )
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<KlageHome />, rootElement);
```

Comment: I have provided working code. This should give you the gist on how to create functional component. Please also post code for `AAA` function which seems to be the component having issue with.

Comment: thanks a lot @tarzen chugh. i did that mistake (capitalize first letter).